# Maven Dependency execution directory

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-3

This is a question about Maven at runtime.

Scenario:

1. A client maven project depends on my module (ModuleA)
   **RESULT**: ModuleA and its transitive dependencies are downloaded into the clients Maven Repo.  Correct?
2. The client maven project is built with Jenkins.
3. During a phase of the Jenkins maven build, the client maven project calls `ModuleA.DoSomethingUseful()`

What is the result of:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Current Path: %s", SomeClassinModuleA.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()))?
```

Is it going to be somewhere under Jenkins workspace or under the maven repo on Jenkins box?

Comment: Is there anyone out there with any insight regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be within the Maven repo, not the Jenkins workspace.